# Make records for database with form in laravel

Tags: database, forms, laravel, eloquent

I tried to fill my database with form by using this syntax

View:

```html
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <h1>Create New Authors Page</h1>

    {{Form::open(array('url'=>'authors/create','action'=>'AuthorsController@buat'))}}

        @include('common.show_error')

        <p>
            {{Form::label('name', 'Name: ')}}<br>
            {{Form::text('name', Input::old('name'))}}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{Form::label('bio','Biography')}}<br>
            {{Form::textarea('bio', Input::old('bio'))}}
        </p>

        <p>{{Form::submit('Add Authors')}}</p>

    {{Form::close()}}
@stop
```

Controller (AuthorsController):

```
public function buat()
{
    Author::create(array(
        'name'=>Input::get('name'),
        'bio'=>Input::get('bio')
    ));

    return Redirect::route('authors')
        ->with('message','New Author Succesfully Added');
}
```

Rotue:

```
Route::post('authors/create', 'AuthorsController@buat');
```

It passed without error, but the database filled nothing... blank without any record..

but. when i used this syntax in controller, it works:

```
public function buat(){
    $authorr = new Author;

    $authorr->name  = Input::get('name');;
    $authorr->bio   = Input::get('bio');;

    $authorr -> save(); 

    return Redirect::route('authors')
        ->with('message','New Author Succesfully Added');
}
```

Please help me to fill database with the first syntax

Comment: Probably `MassAssignementException` was thrown, but you have `debug = false` in `app/config/app.php` so you've seen no error. Check the config, then make sure your model can be filled with the array like described here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in your form you have used:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'authors/create','action'=>'AuthorsController@buat')) }}
```

You should use either `url` or `action` but not both:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'authors/create')) }}
```

Or tthis:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'AuthorsController@buat')) }}
```

BTW, you may use this:

```
$author = Author::create(array(
    'name'=>Input::get('name'),
    'bio'=>Input::get('bio')
));

if($author) {
    return Redirect::route('authors')
                   ->with('message', 'New Author Succesfully Added');
}
```

But make sure you have declared a `$fillable` array in your `Author` model like:

```
protected $fillable = array('name', 'bio');
```

A;so you may declare an empty `$guarde` array instead of `$fillable` to allow any field for mass-assignment, like this:

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

Also, it's useful to enable debugging in `app/config/app.php` file by setting this:

```
debug => true,
```

So you'll get informative error messages.